# how to download the full WET archive from Common Crawl?

Tags: wget

I am interested in the `WET` archives for the latest april 2018 crawl (http://commoncrawl.org/2018/05/april-2018-crawl-archive-now-available/)

Is it possible to download the full `WET` archive at once? I see that the single paths are available on the website, but I would like to avoid needing to iterate over each single file. Is this possible? Am I forced to iterate of every single file?

Disclaimer: I am a `noob` with the command line. Any detailed help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to download the full WET archive at once?

Unless they offer it in a format other than as a series of `gzip` files, it seems unlikely.

**Multiple Archives**

As a side comment, when you are downloading a large data set, splitting things into smaller archives is extremely desirable. Essentially, it allows a connection to be interrupted with a minimal amount of fuss (you've lost only one smallish file). Likewise, assuming one or more files become corrupted during transfer, you only need to re-download those files -- and they are likely to be a lot less hassle than re-downloading a partially downloaded, corrupted, massive single archive.